# smarter sqlalchemy wtf dynamic filter in a flask app

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have a form that filters a table, and i would like the form entry to build a sqlalchemy statement.

Because I have the option "No Filter", i can't just have the form field go into the filter('form field here').  But there must be a better way than doing every permutation like

```
AT= list(set([h.assigned for h in models.Request.query.all()]))
AT.append('No Filter')
form.assigned.choices=zip(AT,AT)
requestlist= models.Request.query.all() 
if form.validate_on_submit():

    if form.status.data=='No Filter' and form.assigned.data=='No Filter' and form.requestor.data=='No Filter':
            requestlist= models.Request.query.all() 
    elif form.status.data != 'No Filter' and form.assigned.data=='No Filter' and form.requestor.data=='No Filter':
        requestlist = db.session.query(models.Request).filter(models.Request.status.like(form.status.data)).all()
    elif form.status.data == 'No Filter' and form.assigned.data!='No Filter' and form.requestor.data=='No Filter':
        requestlist = db.session.query(models.Request).filter(models.Request.assigned.like(form.assigned.data)).all()
    elif form.status.data == 'No Filter' and form.assigned.data=='No Filter' and form.requestor.data!='No Filter':
        requestlist = db.session.query(models.Request).filter(models.Request.requestedBy.like(form.requestor.data)).all()
    elif form.status.data != 'No Filter' and form.assigned.data=='No Filter' and form.requestor.data!='No Filter':
        requestlist = db.session.query(models.Request).filter(models.Request.requestedBy.like(form.requestor.data))\
        .filter(models.Request.status.like(form.status.data)).all()
    elif form.status.data == 'No Filter' and form.assigned.data !='No Filter' and form.requestor.data!='No Filter':
        requestlist = db.session.query(models.Request).filter(models.Request.requestedBy.like(form.requestor.data))\
        .filter(models.Request.assigned.like(form.assigned.data)).all()
    elif form.status.data != 'No Filter' and form.assigned.data !='No Filter' and form.requestor.data =='No Filter':
        requestlist = db.session.query(models.Request).filter(models.Request.status.like(form.status.data))\
        .filter(models.Request.assigned.like(form.assigned.data)).all()
    elif form.status.data != 'No Filter' and form.assigned.data !='No Filter' and form.requestor.data !='No Filter':
        requestlist = db.session.query(models.Request).filter(models.Request.status.like(form.status.data))\
        .filter(models.Request.requestedBy.like(form.requestor.data))\
        .filter(models.Request.assigned.like(form.assigned.data)).all()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add multiple `filter(...)` clauses one after another:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    requestlist = models.Request.query

    if form.status.data != 'No Filter':
        requestlist = requestlist.filter(models.Request.status.like(form.status.data))

    if form.assigned.data != 'No Filter':
        requestlist = requestlist.filter(models.Request.assigned.like(form.assigned.data))

    if form.requestor.data != 'No Filter':
        requestlist = requestlist.filter(models.Request.requestedBy.like(form.requestor.data))

    return requestlist.all()
```

or more generically you could probably do the following:

```
field_names = ['status', 'assigned', 'requestor']
if form.validate_on_submit():
    requestlist = models.Request.query

    for field in field_names:
        f_value = getattr(form, field).data
        if f_value != 'No Filter':
            requestlist = requestlist.filter(getattr(models.Request, field).like(f_value))

    return requestlist.all()
```

*The only problem i see is that sometimes names on the form and the model do not match. An example is `requestedBy` and `requestor`. In this case you might define a dictionary instead of a list in `field_names`.*

Comment: It's not the multiple filter clauses that were the problem.  I was hoping i could write one sqlalchemy query that worked whether a filter term was select or "no filter" was selected e.g. filter(*all) when "no filter" otherwise use the filter term.  thanks for the example though!

Comment: I thought the issue was to reduce the number of permutations from quadratic (`8 = 2**3`) to linear (just 3), which is accomplished. So if you add two more filters, you will have to add just two more lines for a total of 5 instead of a total of `32 (2**5`).  But sure you can improve this to be more generic. Let me try to extend the answer...

Comment: I just updated my original question to more clear.  sorry i threw you off.  also, thanks again for your help.  I work alone, and your responses to my q's and others' have been a huge help!  I'll delete this comment in a bit, but wanted to say a special thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Added another variant of an answer for your consideration.

Comment: the issue with this is that any combination of the filter could be selected, so this only allows filtering on one form field at a time, right?  form.status.data != 'No Filter' and form.assigned.data !='No Filter' and form.requestor.data !='No Filter'.

Comment: No, it covers all possible combinations of the filter. If you look at the code, you will see that filters are added on as-needed basis.